# JqueryMobile Issues DIVs

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have created a simple `.toggle` script on one page to toggle a `DIV`. But when I put this exact same script on another page to toggle another `DIV` the second page script fails... I have tried multiple fixes but nothing works

Here is the script I am using on both pages  The IDs are different but the script is the same

```
<script>

$(document).bind('pageinit', function()  {

    $('#slick-toggle').live('tap', function(event) {
        $("#menu_box").toggle(400);
    });
});

</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Capt. Crunch

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
<script>

$( document ).on( 'pageinit',function(event){

    $('#slick-toggle').on('tap', function(event) {
        $("#menu_box").toggle(400);
    });
});

</script>
```

Hope this helps, let me know about your result.